# Hybris SCSS (sass) Integration

Tags: sass, sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris supports for ".less" to generate css files for storefront by default. In addition to this, hybris has backoffice-sass integration.

backoffice sass integration link:
https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/830f7ed55f804b1980dcfad2f83ce3a7.html

storefront less integration link:
https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8ac7e55f86691014a6a9c4f7224649a0.html

I want to generate css files in "_ui" folder from scss files in "_ui-src" folder. How can i perform scss integration for storefront?

Comment: can you try `ant clean build` ?

Comment: it is not related to "ant clean build". when we build the system, hybris generate  _ui folder from _ui-src. css files in _ui is generated from the less files during the build process.You can see that in the link above. How can i  generate css files from the sccs (not less) during the build phase when i place it into _ui-src ?

Answer (score 1):

Grunt support scss format also. You can modify Gruntfile.js for adding scss files.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I never used Gruntfile.js and it is so unfamiliar for me.  Can you elaborate your answer?